# Angular deployment - apiUrl does not exist on the type {production : boolean}

Tags: angular, laravel

I developed an Angular 7 App with Laravel backend. While trying to build and deploy  for production I got an error.

> src/app/services/user.service.ts(10,32): error TS2339: Property 'apiUrl' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.

On the angular CLI I ran this:

> ng build --prod

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl:   'http://example.com/api',   
};
```

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

 private API_URL= environment.apiUrl;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(email, password) {
const obj = {
  email: email,
  password: password
};
console.log(obj);
this.http.post(this.API_URL + '/login', obj)
    .subscribe(res => console.log('login Done',res));
  }

}
```

On

> ng build --prod

I expect it to build then I put the dist file on the online server.

This is the error:

> src/app/services/user.service.ts(10,32): error TS2339: Property 'apiUrl' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.

Note: I am doing it for the first time.

Comment: You probably didn't change your ```environment.prod.ts```, only your ```environment.prod```. Quote from environment.ts "ng build ---prod` replaces `environment.ts` with `environment.prod.ts"

Comment: How do I change this

Comment: I made a slight mistake while writing. I ment to change your `environment.prod.ts`, in addition to your `environment.ts`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

the `environment.ts` file will be replaced during build,
`ng build --prod` replaces `environment.ts` with `environment.prod.ts` so just add the **apiUrl** property to environment class in `environment.prod.ts` file

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl:   'http://example.com/api', 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need add your property in environment.ts and environment.prod.ts.

[enviroment.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hu7v.png)

[environment.prod.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kQcR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just need add your property in `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check once in **angular.json** and replace as below mentioned

```
  "**fileReplacements**": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"  -> environment.ts 
                }
```

For me before default it is taking enviornment.prod

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).